# EMR config.json option is throwing S3 Region 301 redirect error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, emr, amazon-emr

When creating a new Elastic MapReduce cluster, I've passed in a config json file as a config option.

The bucket that the config file resides in says that its "region" is northern california.

The EMR cluster i'm trying to create is in Oregon.

When I go to finally create the cluster, it says theres an error with the config file, and then the error is the following:

```
Moved Permanently (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 301; Error Code: 
  301 Moved Permanently; Request ID: 9xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

The `EMR_DefaultRole` is being used as the role for the cluster, and that role already has full S3 permissions:

[image]

I don't understand what the error means. Must I re-upload the files and set them to `Oregon` in order for them to work? or is there a way to make this region-agnostic, or just bypass the region problem altogether with IAM permissions in some way?

Comment: How are you mentioning the S3 bucket endpoint? Is it some thing like this?http://<bucketname>.s3.amazonaws.com

Comment: @error2007s `s3://bucket/path/to/file.json` -- where the file and the emr cluster are both in / owned by my account

Comment: This is issue is due to AWS S3 region conflict(Error 301 in AWS S3 is for region Conflict)  can you paste the code you are using without credentials?

Comment: @error2007s I'm creating the cluster using the EMR GUI. there is no code, per se

Comment: Give your "EMR_DefaultRole" or the role for your new EMR access to S3 and then try creating it will work

Comment: @error2007s the `EMR_DefaultRole` has already been granted `AmazonS3FullAccess`, and this role is used in other regions and works fine. its uniquely here in Oregon that is having this issue

Comment: I tried to recreate the above steps it worked for me I guess there is Region conflict in the config file that you are using. Can you paste the config file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115443/discussion-between-kristian-and-error2007s).